# ЧПУ, так сложно...

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Помогите, если разбираетесь. Никак не могу изменить ЧПУ, сколько бессоных ночей провел над одной лишь ерундой. 
Как это - **http://www.site.ru/~cat/54/index.html**
заменить на это - **http://www.site.ru/page.html** (можно и **http://www.site.ru/~cat/page.html**)
Сайт на ЦМС от Фабрики Сайтов, сколько бы их я не трезвонил они лишь твердят, что дело в htaccess. Уже перебробовал бесчисленное множество разных перенаправлений, но ничего не помогает.
Сам Htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*).fsdev.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(~(.*))$ /index.php
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\.(html|js|xsl)$ /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.site.ru/404.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Может такой конфиг на нужную мысль наведет:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]

    RewriteRule ^/*$ index.php

    RewriteRule ^production/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ production.php?active=$1&subcat=$2 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^production/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ production.php?active=$1&subcat=$2 [QSA]

    RewriteRule ^production/([0-9]+)$ production.php?active=$1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^production/([0-9]+)/$ production.php?active=$1 [QSA]

    RewriteRule ^production$ production.php
    RewriteRule ^production/$ production.php
```